# Problem with basic usage of std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I'm trying to make a simple template function that given some parameters, it outputs them with a space in between. Some of those can be elements of an enum, and in that case I want to output its integer value.

This is the code I have:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

// Output integer value if parameter is an element of an enum
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
constexpr std::ostream& debug(const T& a) {
  cerr << (int)(a);
  return cerr;
}

// Output parameter otherwise
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<T>::value>>
constexpr std::ostream& debug(const T& a) {
  cerr << a;
  return cerr;
}

// Print parameters separated by a space
template<typename T, typename ...U>
constexpr std::ostream& debug(const T& a, const U&... b) {
  debug(a) << ' ';
  debug(b...);
  return cerr;
}

template<typename ...U>
constexpr void debug(const U&... a) {
  debug(a...) << std::endl;
}

enum class Animal{Dog, Cat};

int main() {
  debug(Animal::Dog);
  debug(Animal::Dog, Animal::Cat);
  debug("Hello");
  debug(100, 'A');
  debug(Animal::Dog, "Hello", "Bye");
}
```

Commenting the last three lines it says that the second function is a redeclaration of the first. Any ideas on how to solve this or why it does not work?

Comment: Did you mean to write `Animals::Dog` etc. in your example? Always put real code in your question please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I noticed you already edited your code snippet to make it more complete but it still issues more compiler errors than the single one you described. Can you fix the remaining errors?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The second template parameter is defaulted to `void`.

Comment: See the [notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: To me, the title reads as if you are trying to implement `std::enable_if` itself, not just _use_ it...

Comment: @MaxLanghof seems to be a matter of translation, I read it quite often. Fixed that

Comment: Unrelated, but I doubt that `std::ostream`'s `operator <<` is `constexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default template arguments are not part of the function definition. Use a dummy parameter instead, so that the second argument has a different type:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, int> = 0>
constexpr std::ostream& debug(const T& a) {
  std::cerr << (int)(a);
  return std::cerr;
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<T>::value, int> = 0>
constexpr std::ostream& debug(const T& a) {
  std::cerr << a;
  return std::cerr;
}
```